# Getting Pip working in PyCharm on MacOS 10.14.5

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm

I'm a python noob working through this intro to python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw. (definitely no need to watch this. Just adding it as context)

It's been going really well, except now I'm up to the part where I need to use pip, and despite having downloaded version 3.8 of Python, it keeps telling me that it doesn't even have pip installed.

I'm wondering if anyone could walk me through what the issue might be and how to actually start using pip in PyCharm.

I've tried downloading pip and installing it but even that doesn't seem to work. If anyone has an ultra-hand-holdy solution (very much for a noob) that would be appreciated.

I feel like the problem might be that I'm putting things in the wrong directories or something? Obviously there are some built-in versions on Python (2.x) already on the Mac so maybe they are interfering?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what happens if you do ```pip install ipython``` for example

Comment: I would *highly* suggest you do *not* use Python 3.8, but 3.7. A lot of 3rd-party packages are not yet available for 3.8, so you set yourself up for failure - especially as a newcomer.

Comment: The video is 4 hours long - you can't expect us to look through the video to see what it's telling you to do. Please update your question to say which commands you are running and where. Python 3.8 should come with `pip`, so you can use `python3 -m pip install` instead of `pip install` to install modules.

Comment: My final bit of advice is to [use a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). `python3 -m venv myvenv` will create a virtual environment, then you can run `source myvenv/bin/activate` to activate it. Once inside the virtual environment, you can use `python -m pip install` to install packages.

Comment: @Alasdair very much understand. I've changed the post to indicate I don't expect anyone to watch it. Was just as context. Thanks for letting me know though.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for advice re: virtual environment. Yes I wasn't sure really what the difference was between virtual and the other options. Will try.

Comment: Thanks @E.Serra for your quick response. Alasdair's answer has solved the problem for now but if I bump into anything further down the road I might come back to your answers. Thank you. Didn't realise people replied so fast on here.

Comment: Also thanks @deets (as above)

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, the version of Python that is used when you use the command `python` is the 2.x version, which doesn't have `pip`. So if you want to use python in terminal, you should call it as `python3` and `pip3` for using the pip command.

If you want to set a different Python version as the default one, you can do that. Here is a tutorial that can get you started with that (there's a plethora of other tutorials if this one isn't clear enough): https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

For using PyCharm specifically, you can setup the Python interpreter that is used with PyCharm by going to `Preferences(or Settings) -> Project:[name of your project] -> Project Interpreter` and then chose the desired Python Interpreter from the drop down menu. You can also create a virtual environment there by clicking on the cog icon and choosing `Add`. This is the preferred way and very convenient to keep installed packages local to your project. After you're done with that, open up PyCharms terminal (at the bottom of your PyCharm window) and you should be able to normally use pip with the command `pip`.

Alternatively, you can install Python packages in PyCharm using their built in `package manager` that you can find in the same window where you set your Python Interpreter. Below the dropdown menu you'll see a `+` sign, where you can click to add packages.

[image: Project Interpreter window]

Comment: For 3.8, the command may even be pip3.8. It depends on what's installed, I guess.

Comment: Yes indeed, it probably depends on which version is installed.

Comment: Thanks @CurlyAlpaca for such an in-depth response. I've found Alasdair's approach is working for now. But I may refer back to your answer in the future, especially if I go to set up a new project. Thanks again. Didn't realise people replied so quickly on here.

Comment: @Lordfirespeed Thanks for your help! (see also above) :)